# AutoMapper configuration resets when using ASP.MVC 3.0

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, automapper

In this scenario I'm using `AutoMapper` library in ASP.MVC 3.0 to handle mapping between dto and model objects. I tried to place all AutoMapper configuration code in one place, so it has following structure:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    ConfigureAutoMapper();
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    SetupWindsorContainer();
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}

...

private void ConfigureAutoMapper()
{
    Mapper.CreateMap<SampleDto, SampleModel>();
    ...
}
```

This code is placed in `MvcApplication` class. With debugger I checked that this code is executed but when I try to perform `Mapper.Map<>` in Controller code i get exeception saying that mapping hasn't been registered. I had suspected that this is related to how ASP.MVC handles `AppDomains` but it seems to be the same `AppDomain` in both methods (registration code and mapping code). ASAIR this code executed properly on ASP.MVC 2.0

EDIT 1:
According to MS documentation on `Application_Start`:

> "Called when the first resource (such as a page) in an ASP.NET
>   application is requested. The Application_Start method is called only
>   one time during the life cycle of an application. You can use this
>   method to perform startup tasks such as loading data into the cache
>   and initializing static values.
>
> You should set only static data during application start. Do not set
>   any instance data because it will be available only to the first
>   instance of the HttpApplication class that is created."

AutoMapper configuration is static class so I think it should work properly when initialized in `Application_Start` but it doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you install **[WebActivator](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/WebActivator)** NuGet package and set up your AutoMapper using it. It guarantees the execution at the startup and you can extract your setup code to a separate class and not pollute Global.asax. What is more, you can keep your AutoMapper code in a separate dll (ie., in a Service layer) and WebActivator will still run your code without modifying your MVC project at all!

Answer (score 0):

[Life Cycle Events and the Global.asax file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473.aspx)

> The Application_Start and Application_End methods are special methods that do not represent HttpApplication events. ASP.NET calls them once for the lifetime of the application domain, not for each HttpApplication instance.

You can use `Application_BeginRequest` instead although Jakub's answer does sound like a good approach!

Comment: You shouldn't put you AutoMapper config in `BeginRequest` as the config doesn't have to be recreated on each requests (for performance reasons)

Comment: I agree -- just pointing out why it wasn't working and a poor workaround for it.

Comment: Take a look on my `EDIT 1` note. I would disagree that this code cannot be executed from `Application_Start` because its enough to call it once for AppDomain.